# What is the complete shloka on marriage ages written in new Vishvnath temple, Varanasi

Tags: scripture, temple, marriage, tradition, identification-request

In 2013-14, I visited new Vishvnath temple (in BHU), Varanasi. Inside temple, many shlokas are written on its wall. One of them states the suiatable age of marriage,  I remember only few words from it:

For man the suitable age of marriage was written as पञ्चविंशति (25) and for woman as षोडश (16).

Can anyone please tell the complete shloka and it's source?